# Can a VFP class get a collection of it's own methods at run-time?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-foxpro

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish, in Visual FoxPro.  I want to write a parent UnitTest class, that can be subclassed to create individual unit tests. I am hoping that the parent UnitTest can have a MainMethod which examines itself, and then finds and executes all of it's own methods which begin with "test_".

This way I can go forward writing appropriately named functions in my unit tests, and the parent will know how to run them without any additional input from me.  But, I can't locate any way to get this information from VFP at run-time, without having the child class explicitly define a collection of method names or something to that regard (which is exactly what I'm hoping to avoid).

Here's is a basic stub:

```
define class UnitTest as custom  && would be abstract if VFP supported that

    procedure MainMethod()
        && run all methods that begin with test_
    endproc

enddefine

define class AUnitTest as UnitTest

    procedure test_thingA()
        ...
    endproc

    procedure test_thingB()
        ...
    endproc

enddefine
```

Would love anyone's ideas on how to get at the child methods from the parent.  (Also open to a better implementation idea, if I'm going about this wrong, I think the basic idea of what I'm going for is clear).

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMEMBERS() function could be used to get a list of methods.

```
loX = CREATEOBJECT("AUnitTest")
loX.MainMethod()
STORE .NULL. TO loX
RETURN


define class UnitTest as custom

    procedure MainMethod()
        LOCAL lcCommand, lcName, lcType, lnMemberNo, lnTotalMembers
        LOCAL ARRAY laMembers(1)

        m.lnTotalMembers = AMEMBERS(laMembers, THIS, 1, "U")
        FOR m.lnMemberNo = 1 TO m.lnTotalMembers
            m.lcName = m.laMembers[m.lnMemberNo,1]
            m.lcType = m.laMembers[m.lnMemberNo,2]

            IF (m.lcType == "Method") AND (LEFT(m.lcName, 5) == "TEST_")
                m.lcCommand = "THIS." + m.lcName + "()"
                &lcCommand
            ELSE
                * do nothing
            ENDIF
        ENDFOR

    endproc

enddefine

define class AUnitTest as UnitTest

    procedure test_thingA()
        WAIT WINDOW "Testing Thing A"
    endproc

    procedure test_thingB()
        WAIT WINDOW "Testing Thing B"
    endproc

    procedure NotATest()
        WAIT WINDOW "Not A Test"
    endproc

enddefine
```